# What is the ruling on printing pictures without hanging them?

Tags: halal-haram, image

What is the ruling on printing pictures of humans (using a printer)? I am aware that we are not allowed to hang pictures but are we allowed to print and keep them without hanging it?

I was going to print a picture like this one:

[image: A picture of hands against the sky]

Is it permissible if it doesn't show the face (only part of the body)? Also, what if the picture is only a shadow, is it fine?

Answer (score -1):

You are not allowed to create pictures and unless you didnt create the picture or if you dont hang these images in your house etc then it may be fine. Ive read that you arent allowed to draw the faces of humans some say that you cant draw it at all but that picture is just of the hand so it may be alright.

Comment: thankyou for answering but i dont still understand it clearly,,,so are we allowed to print picture without hanging them?